# Validate source code authenticity from git repository

Tags: git

Suppose there is a bug in `git` causing developers commit incorrect changes to the repository so that sources checked out do not match what they have locally under same hash. I understand that hash protects structure of git objects, not checked out sources.

Does git have any safeguard mechanisms that make this less likely than one might think?

Comment: Wouldn't `git diff` or `git status` show it if a file in the working tree didn't match the blob in the git object database?

Answer (score 2):

That would only happen if there is a SHA1 collision, meaning if the content SHA1 is the same as the one stored in the Git repo.

You can check that by [computing yourself the SHA1 of a file you just checked out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7225329/6309).
See also "[How does git compute file hashes?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/552725/6309)".

The probability of a collision (two different content for the same SHA1) is *very* low: see "[Why does Git use a cryptographic hash function?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28792805/6309)".