# Git hash output does not match sha1sum, why?

Tags: bash, git, git-bash, sha

I've seen this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28792784/why-does-git-use-a-cryptographic-hash-function), and it mentions that Git uses a SHA-1 hash for the version that I am using. However, when I'm comparing the output of `git hash-object` to the familiar `sha1sum`, I get different results. For example:

```
$ git --version
git version 2.17.1
$ git hash-object data/letter.txt
2e65efe2a145dda7ee51d1741299f848e5bf752e
$ sha1sum data/letter.txt
86f7e437faa5a7fce15d1ddcb9eaeaea377667b8  data/letter.txt
```

I am following this [post](https://codewords.recurse.com/issues/two/git-from-the-inside-out). The file `letter.txt` contains a single letter 'a'.

Why would these commands produce different results?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+calculate+sha-1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The hashes do not match because Git prepends a header (`blob #{content.length}\0`) to the data/content (of the file).

cf. https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects